# Puppeteer - 'error' event handler triggers immediately upon setting .on('error') handler. How to find out why?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, puppeteer

I am trying to add a "Page.on('error',...) event handler to catch any page errors and quit gracefully.

In this script, there's a function "reportStatus" and for now, all it does is print the given string and execute the callback function right after.

The quit() function just closes node, executing `process.exit()` and printing "EXIT" in the console.

The following is what I've written in the script in order to

```
  var launchArgs = {
     headless: false,
     ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  },
  browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchArgs),
  pupPage = await browser.newPage();

  console.log("Doing stuff before...")
  
  console.log("Setting error func.");
  pupPage.on(
    'error',
    async function () {
      console.log("Error'd");
      console.log("Arguments: ");
      console.log(arguments); // Any sorta stacktrace we can check and print?

      await reportStatus('WEB_APPLICATION_ERROR', function () {
        await quit();
      });
    }.call(this)
  );

  console.log("OPENING PAGE");
  response = await pupPage.goto(url); // Open print report page.

  console.log("Doing stuff after...");
```

When I execute the above statements, this is what appears in the console.

```
    Doing stuff before...
    Setting error func.
    Error'd
    Arguments:
    undefined
    WEB_APPLICATION_ERROR
    QUITTING
    ______________ EXIT ______________
```

The way I understand it, **it seems that setting the error event-handler function immediately triggers the provided error-handler function.** **The 'goto' doesn't even get called yet from what it looks like.**

**Is there a way to find what exactly caused the 'error' event to fire?** There doesn't seem to be any arguments passed into the event-handler function that I could use to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Is there a reason you have `.call(this)`? That will call the error handler function immediately, which probably doesn't make sense. `await reportStatus('WEB_APPLICATION_ERROR', function () {` looks highly unusual. Usually, you either `await` or provide an async callback, not both. `await quit();` looks like invalid syntax--there's no `async` on the function it's in.

Comment: I see, that's my mistake. the `quit` and `reportStatus` function was out of scope, so I did the `.call(this)` to make sure that function isn't out of scope. I wasn't aware that `call` would literally call the function immediately. Thanks for pointing that out! I've replaced it with `bind` and now the error doesn't get triggered anymore.

Comment: You could use an arrow function, which binds `this` automatically

Comment: Regarding async `reportStatus`, that function will eventually send status information to an API. I intend to do this by sending a PUT request to the API. The `quit` on the other hand originally had more going on, but I'm going to remove the await now

Comment: I see! Thanks for the tip! I'll give the arrow function a try.

Comment: Yeah, `reportStatus` probably doesn't return a promise if it has a result callback, unless it's poorly designed. The whole point of promises is to get rid of async callbacks, so having both is very unusual. Another minor point: `process.exit()` is a rather violent way to exit the process. I would do a graceful browser shutdown with `browser.close()` and direct the code flow to finish executing so all your cleanup handlers can run properly.

Comment: Alright, I'll try implementing your suggestions. Thanks @ggorlen